# WebPack importing react custom packages in another folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am enhancing a website with ReactJS.
My folder structure looks something like this:

```
 _npm
   node_modules
   package.json
   package-lock.json
   webpack.config.js
 _resources
   js
     react
       reactapp1.js
       reactapp2.js
       components
         FormDisplay.js
```

I want to import a custom reactjs package into the FormDisplay component.
When I enter:

```
import PlacesAutocomplete from 'react-places-autocomplete'
```

This doesn't work. But if I enter:

```
import PlacesAutocomplete from "./../../../_npm/node_modules/react-places-autocomplete";
```

This works. I understand why this is the case. I was wondering if there was a way that I can just enter:

```
import PlacesAutocomplete from 'react-places-autocomplete';
```

How do I make it work with just that line of code, without having to find the path to node_modules folder?

My webpack config:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

const PATHS = {
    app: path.join(__dirname, "../_resources/react/"),
    build: path.join(__dirname, '../wordpress_site/wp-content/themes/custom_theme/assets/js/'),
  };

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        reactapp1: path.join(PATHS.app, "reactapp1.js"),
        reactapp2: path.join(PATHS.app, "reactapp2.js")
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        //path: path.join(__dirname,  "dist")
        path: PATHS.build
    },
    module:{
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js?$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ["env", "react"],
                        plugins: ["transform-class-properties"]
                    }
                }
            }

        ]// rules array
    }, // module
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using webpack's [resolve-modules](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-modules)?

```
 resolve: {
   modules: ['_npm/node_modules']
 }
```

Might work